# elastic search for AngularJS -- Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch, cors

I have Installed elasticsearch-6.3.1 in windows & try to filter the data by using following  code in angular 1,it gives CORS error

```
$http({
            url: 'http://localhost:9200/empinfo/employeedetails/_search',
            method: "POST",
            data: "{ 'query': { 'query_string': { 'query': 'Sujit','fields':['name'] } } }",
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(data);
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        });
```

My Elastic search error in angular.js

[image: 1]

Although I have added Allow CORS in elasticsearch.yml file.

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: The $http `.success` method has been [deprecated and removed from V1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angularjs-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Answer (score 1):

You need to uncomment the lines in your yml file.
Simply remove '#' from the beginning of each line. Restart your Elasticsearch.